# Should I store all database data in memory node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I have two options when it comes to a server I am developing.

Option a) when the server start, extract all data from database and store it on memory as objects.

Option b) everytime a data is required, extract it from database, transform it into object and return that. Dont store all data on memory.

I'm kind of afraid that if there is too much data stored in memory the app crashes. But I'm not sure how this is suppose to be handle.

Which is the right way to handle this?

Fill free to extend another option.

Comment: What are your data requirements in terms of size? complexity of queries?
This method has some major drawbacks, so it definitely depends on your server load as well as other factors. For example, You are going to have a bad time trying to scale your application (more than 1 server instance, or even nodejs native clustering).

Comment: which one ? option a or option b?

Comment: I'm talking about a. Both have advantages and disadvantages, please try and provide more information

Comment: What kind of information? well this is the process. When i start the server, the initialization of the server make a simple query which extract all user data. Each User response gets an js-object .  Every User Object have all pertinent data. If any modification is being done, the object get modifies, and a modifying query is sent to DB. This is basically what happens in a nutshell. So all interactions are made to objects.

Comment: That is perfectly clear; What is not clear, however, is what is your expected server load and / or future scaling requirements. In my opinion, the correct solution greatly depends on your scale; How many users are there going to be, how many users using the system at a time, etc.

Comment: so, option a is a valid option?

Comment: You're completely ignoring my questions. It depends on your scale.

Comment: Why do you want to store data in memory ?

Comment: @nadavvadan, im not ignoring your question, it has nothing to do with scale. If this is the correct way, or the best way, no matter the model, scale will always be an issue. The objective is to handle the thing the best way posible, and thats my question... which is the best way. For figure of speech, imagine 1,000,000 users, and 50k users using the app at the same time atleast 10 times a day.

Comment: @TGrif Couse its looks like is the simplest way to have acces to data.

Comment: I disagree, which is why I have raised those questions in the first place. An app serving 1000 users with no more than 50 at a time, for example, does not require any special measures to increase performance, for the average application. 

However, for a larger-scale project, it might be worth the effort and extra ma maintenance to use some sort of caching, such as your option `a`.

For scaling, you should consider `Redis` or similar for caching the data.

There are drawbacks to each of the above. 

There are other things to consider, such as your deadline for the project, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit of both.

You can store some data in memory. For example if your database holds some settings which are some sort of constants and are not thousands of lines, then you can load them in memory. If you have some data that are accessed very frequently and are not being updated very often, you can also load them at runtime and keep them in memory.

If you have some data that expect to change frequently and/or are going to grow extensively, such as user data, or content. Load them from db everytime they are required.

If your application is a large scale app with high traffic, you might want to add some caching system which will basically store some data in memory or file and update it when it is changed or when it expires with a time to live property.